# Restoring Laravel's Homestead after critical error

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Homestead via Vagrant for my Laravel environment. When I ran `vagrant up` today, there was a critical error saying that the box is inaccessible.

One of the instructions that I found on the web suggested unregistering the VM by using its machine uuid, which I did:

```
> VBoxManage.exe unregistervm [uuid]
```

After unregistering the status of Homestead box changed from **inaccessible** to **not created**.

Next step was to register the box, which I do like this:

```
> VBoxManage.exe registervm "C:\Users\Rhino\VirtualBox VMs\homestead\box-disk1.vmdk"
```

However the command above throws the following error:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Start tag expected, '<' not found.
VBoxManage.exe: error: Location: 'C:\Users\Rhino\VirtualBox VMs\homestead\box-disk1.vmdk', line 1 (0), column 1.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out. There was probably a step missing in the guide I found - creation. All the steps again:

**(1)**
Unregister the box with machine uuid. The uuid can be found e.g. in the .vbox-prev file in your homestead virtual machine folder. Run this when you retrieve the uuid:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe unregistervm [uuid]
```

**(2)**
Create the box with `--register` flag:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe createvm --name "C:\Users\Rhino\VirtualBox VMs\homestead\box-disk1.vmdk" --register
```

**(3)**
Delete the folder in which your homestead vm is kept (I guess it's by default created in **VirtualBox VMs** folder)

**(4)**
Run `vagrant up`